# Get count of duplicate dimensions in Google Data Studio for custom visualization

Tags: looker-studio

I am creating a custom visualization in Google Data Studio.  I have a single dimension which for example may be city names.  Say I have the data below in a google sheet as the data source.  The issue I am having is when I get the data from data.tables.DEFAULT any duplicate entries are removed.  So in this case I only get 10 results.  Ideally I would either want them all including duplicates or I could also live with if a secondary value in the array that is passed with a count of how many there were.

```
Cities
San Martin
Cincinnati
Tulsa
Vallejo
San Martin
Gastonia
Yucaipa
Tempe
Worcester
Denver
San Martin
Cincinnati
Tulsa
Vallejo
Orlando
Gastonia
Yucaipa
Tempe
Worcester
Denver
San Martin
Cincinnati



let rowData = data.tables.DEFAULT;
  console.log(rowData);
```

When I console log I only have an array of 10 variables.

More information
I can't copy array out of console log but it would basically look like this.

```
[
  {barDimension: ["San Martin"]},
  {barDimension: ["Cincinnati"]},
  {barDimension: ["Tulsa"]},
  {barDimension: ["Vallejo"]},
  {barDimension: ["Gastonia"]},
  {barDimension: ["Yucaipa"]},
  {barDimension: ["Tempe"]},
  {barDimension: ["Worcester"]},
  {barDimension: ["Denver"]},
  {barDimension: ["Orlando"]}
]
```

Here is my manifest file.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "concepts",
      "label": "Concepts",
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": "barDimension",
          "label": "Dimension",
          "type": "DIMENSION",
          "options": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "style": [
    {
      "id": "color",
      "label": "Colors",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "FONT_COLOR",
          "id": "barColor",
          "label": "Bar Color",
          "defaultValue": "black"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When I look at the docs for a tableFormat object, see here https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/library-reference#table_object ... it seems to contain multiple fields which are "headers" and "rows".  Can you elaborate on the full set of data returned by your console.log?

Comment: added some additional info.  I would think I would get each row from my data source and not only the distinct ones.  So I would expect an array of 23 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour described above is correct: Data Studio returns a distinct set of dimensions in `data.tables.DEFAULT`.

If you require a count of these dimensions, you will need to add a metric, like `COUNT` in your Data configuration.

This is however, the user needs to do. You can only enable him to do this by supplying a metric field.

Comment: I added a second dimension which had a unique id.  That way I was able to get all rows as and do all my calculations within the code.  Thanks